# IntegrityError (news_post.hashTag may not be NULL)

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am deploying my web site, which is written in **Django==1.8** and **Python==3.6**. When I firstly created a model of the project I added a column named *hashtag* to the table ***Post***, so after removing this column, my ***Post*** model class looks like below:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='$
    club = ChainedForeignKey(
        Club,  
        chained_field='league', 
        chained_model_field='league',  
        show_all=False,  
    )
    player = ChainedForeignKey(
        Player,  
        chained_field='club',  
        chained_model_field='club',  
        show_all=False,  
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    img = models.ImageField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = UserForeignKey(auto_user_add=True, verbose_name='The user that is automatically assigned', related_name='posts')
```

As you can see there is no column named **hashtag**.

Whenever I want to add a post to my website, it says

```
IntegrityError at /admin/news/post/add/
news_post.hashTag may not be NULL
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://68.183.188.14:8000/admin/news/post/add/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
news_post.hashTag may not be NULL
Exception Location: /home/firdavsbek/futbik_version_7/djangoen/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 318
Python Executable:  /home/firdavsbek/futbik_version_7/djangoen/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.8
Python Path:    
['/home/firdavsbek/futbik_version_7',
 '/home/firdavsbek/futbik_version_7/djangoen/lib64/python36.zip',
 '/home/firdavsbek/futbik_version_7/djangoen/lib64/python3.6',
 '/home/firdavsbek/futbik_version_7/djangoen/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/home/firdavsbek/futbik_version_7/djangoen/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Вт, 28 Май 2019 20:35:54 +0500
```

but there is not a column as you have seen before...

What I did is just `python manage.py makemigrations news(this is my app name)` and `python manage.py migrate`, that's it!

I cannot solve this problem, if you have any idea, I really be very thankful to you!

It is an output of ***python manage.py showmigrations*** command:

```
 [X] 0001_initial
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
news
 [X] 0001_initial
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

And it is a *00011_initial.py* file in **migrations** folder:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
import smart_selects.db_fields
import django.db.models.deletion
import django_userforeignkey.models.fields
from django.conf import settings


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Post',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, serialize=False, auto_created=True)),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                ('title_en', models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('title_ru', models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('body', models.TextField(max_length=4000)),
                ('body_en', models.TextField(max_length=4000, null=True)),
                ('body_ru', models.TextField(max_length=4000, null=True)),
                ('img', models.ImageField(upload_to='')),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('club', smart_selects.db_fields.ChainedForeignKey(to='news.Club', chained_field='league', chained_model_field='league')),
                ('created_by', django_userforeignkey.models.fields.UserForeignKey(verbose_name='The user that is automatically assigned', blank=True, null=True, editab$
                ('league', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, related_name='posts', to='news.League')),
                ('player', smart_selects.db_fields.ChainedForeignKey(to='news.Player', chained_field='club', chained_model_field='club')),
            ],
        ),
```

Comment: you do not have Hashtag table ?

Comment: When you removed your column, are you sure that a new migration (to remove the field) was created? Take a look at your migration folder if you find a migration for that field.

Comment: @gachdavit Sorry for late respond. I was not able to answer! I removed hashtag column before, but somehow it was asked while saving a new post...

Comment: @DaniloAkamine Hi, sorry for late respond! How do I check whether it is in my migration file?

Comment: I opened a file of migration named 0001_initial.py and checked whether I have not field named **hashtag**. I have not a filed named **hashtag** in ***Post*** table

Comment: @FirdavsNarzullayev Every change in your models you must run `makemigrations` again in order to generate new migrations.
So, after you removed `hashtag` from models.py should you run `makemigrations ` again?

Comment: For example, you should have `migration_01` adding the field and also `migration_02` removing the field.
These two commands (create table, alter table remove column) will run in your database after you run `migrate`.

Comment: @DaniloAkamine I did all migrations commands, such as ***python manage.py makemigrations & python manage.py migrate***.

Comment: @FirdavsNarzullayev and can't you find any migration "removing" the field? how many migrations (files) you have?

Comment: @DaniloAkamine I edited my question above look, there is an output of ***python manage.py showmigrations*** command:

Comment: @FirdavsNarzullayev take a look inside all files (showed from showmigrations) and look for some code like this `migrations.RemoveField(model_name='Post', name='hashtag')`. If you can't find, probably it's missing that migration. Remember, when you add a field you must generate a migration for that and when you remove the field you also must generate a migration to remove it.

Comment: I got it thnx @DaniloAkamine

Comment: @DaniloAkamine I solved my problem by resetting my migrations, with the help of this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html). That's it)